# Navigation Menu: Alternating colors for badges (colors should be in sequential order)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

This is the function defined in MainService.ts, it can change the color set in badgesColorSet ,I have 3 colors defined in the json config already and i want these 3 colors to change everytime I open the website lets it is red then i refresh the page it should be green and then i refresh again it should be blue. so is this function correct and should i use for loop ?and I think i need to divide it by something so it increments and goes from 0 ,1 ,2 as index?

```
getIteriateColor(){
        //gets  color out of color set from turnkey.config file for badges
    let  badgesColorSet = 0; badgesColorSet < Array.length; badgesColorSet++;
        console.log(badgesColorSet);
        return badgesColorSet;
```

the colors are defined in turnkey-config.json

```
"badgesColorSet":["#ffff00","#f51307","#0cc902"],
```

this code is in the mainservice to define the background color of the material badge

```
badge: {bg: this.getNextColor() , fg: 'white' , title: moduleBadge},
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should a Math.random or something and deduce a color based on the random value

Comment: If you definitely want it to go to the next color on a refresh you are going to have to remember what color you were on before. How are you doing that? (e.g. setting a cookie??).

Comment: @mak15 no i dont want colors to appear randomly i want the colors to go sequentially iteirate "badgesColorSet":["#ffff00","#f51307","#0cc902"],

Comment: @AHaworth  i dont want colors to appear randomly i want the colors to go sequentially iteirate "badgesColorSet":["#ffff00","#f51307","#0cc902"]

Comment: Yes, which is why I asked how are you going to remember what color was shown last time? Are you using a cookie?

Comment: @AHaworth i found the answer Thank you soo much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `getNextColor()` calls `getIteriateColor()` to get the next color.

On `getIteriateColor()` let's loop through `"badgesColorSet":["#ffff00","#f51307","#0cc902"]` and starting again from `[0]` when iterate reaches `[2]`.

To remember what color was last used we should store it somewhere on the client where the state remains (e.g localStorage), that way we know what color to choose next.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  badgesColorSet = ['#ffff00', '#f51307', '#0cc902'];
  badgesColorSelected: string;
  constructor() {
    this.getIteriateColor();
  }

  getIteriateColor() {
    // if there is no color in localStorage, set the first color
    if (!localStorage.getItem('badgesColorSelected')) {
      localStorage.setItem('badgesColorSelected', this.badgesColorSet[0]);
    } else {
      // if there is color, select the next color
      const storageColor = localStorage.getItem('badgesColorSelected');
      const colorIndex = this.badgesColorSet.indexOf(storageColor);
      if (colorIndex + 1 > this.badgesColorSet.length - 1) {
        this.badgesColorSelected = this.badgesColorSet[0];
        localStorage.setItem('badgesColorSelected', this.badgesColorSet[0]);
      } else {
        this.badgesColorSelected = this.badgesColorSet[colorIndex + 1];
        localStorage.setItem('badgesColorSelected',this.badgesColorSet[colorIndex + 1]
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mw7s49?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Or for backend something similar except without localStorage.

```js
  badgesColorSet: string[] = ['#ffff00', '#f51307', '#0cc902'];
  badgesColorSelected: string;

  getIteriateColor() {
    if (!this.badgesColorSelected) {
      this.badgesColorSelected = this.badgesColorSet[0];
    } else {
      let nextColorIndex = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.badgesColorSet.length; i++) {
        if (this.badgesColorSet[i] === this.badgesColorSelected) {
          if (i <= this.badgesColorSet.length - 2) {
          nextColorIndex = i + 1;
          break;
          } 
        }
      }
      this.badgesColorSelected = this.badgesColorSet[nextColorIndex];
    }
    console.log('current color is: ', this.badgesColorSelected);
  }
```

```
badge: {bg: badgesColorSelected , fg: 'white' , title: moduleBadge},
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ,i used the backend version it is so helpful and it worked it changed the color whenever i refreshed but and now i have a small quick question when i tried adding more colors to the array the colors are not changing lets say red and green and doesnt change whenever i refresh the page but and i want to use consloe.log('') or some other method to test it out

Comment: if you help me with this forsure i will donate money to you good sir ! This is the code for the material badge that needs to be fixed, it should already have the index saved starting from zero and increments and it shouldnt use indexOf or color index and the property should be changed to number instead of string so it doesnt make loops to find the index so the code is cleaner and faster

Comment: Length of the array doesn't matter, add however many colors you want as you want. Basically what happens is when you call `getIteriateColor()` then `badgesColorSelected` will be set to a new color from `badgesColorSet[]`. I updated the last example slightly.

Comment: yes it worked but i mean is there any other way to do it to make it more cleaner or simpler , for example if we use foreach  or something else and i will send the donation as soon as possible  thank you !

Comment: Looks simple and clean for me. If you have better ideas using `forEach` be my guest and show us your version. It's always possible to refactor. There is no one definitive good version.

Comment: yes it is amazing work sir but if its possible to make the functioanlity work without indexof i would be glad thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "make something" when you refresh, you use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) I imagine you can use some like

```
  color
  badgesColorSet=["#ffff00","#f51307","#0cc902"]
  ngOnInit(){
    let index=localStorage.getItem('indexColor')!=undefined?
                       +localStorage.getItem('indexColor'): -1
    index=(index+1)%3;
    localStorage.setItem('indexColor',''+index)
    this.color=this.badgesColorSet[index]
    
  }
```

See that at first, if not exist localstorage.getItem('indexColor') (that's undefined) You makes index=0 and store "0", the next time you store "1","2","0","1","2"... -localStorage only admit "strings" it's because you use `''`+index to convert to string and `+`localStorage.getItem('indexColor') to conver to number

The use of ìndex=(index+1)%3 makes that the value of index becomes 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...

NOTE: You can use also [sesionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (Just replace in code `localstorage` by `sessionStorage`)

Comment: Is there a way for it not to be on localstorage and actually this is the closest answer till now since the site is run on servers and on runtime so possibly if there is something else other than localstorage thank you !!

Comment: Always you want that "after refresh" makes something with an old value you need "store" a variable in client using localstore, cookies, [session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or indexdbs -perhafps you're looking for session- (well, if you has a typical app with users and depends of users you can store in the server in some field of the dbs). Other option can be use a `Math.floor(Math.random()*3)` to get a random number between 0,1 or 2. but you can not sure the order. Math random can give you two 0s or a 1 and 0) in two differents calls

Comment: Is there a reason you store every value ever used in local storage rather than just store the last used color in a cookie?

Comment: read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies). they explain better than me. NOTE: Really I'm more used to use localstore, so it's not a good reason

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use [ngClass] and condition by pointing to the css classes that you have predefined with those colors.

Answer (score 0):

In Component:

```js
interface Link {
  label: string;
  route: string;
  icon: string;
}

links: Link[] = [ // your links ]
```

Inside Template:

```html
<nav>
  <a *ngFor="let link of links; let odd = odd" [href]="link.route" [class.odd]="odd">{{link.label}}</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for the function i did some change to Joosep.P thanks to him .

```
getIteriateColor() {

    if (!this.badgesColorSelected) {
      this.badgesColorSelected = 0;
    } else {
      const colorIndex = this.badgesColorSelected;
      if (colorIndex + 1 > this.badgesColorSet.length - 1) {
        this.badgesColorSelected = this.badgesColorSet[0];
      } else {
        this.badgesColorSelected = this.badgesColorSet[colorIndex + 1];
      }
    }
    console.log('current color is: ', this.badgesColorSelected);
    
    return this.badgesColorSelected;
}
}
```

this is for the config

```
 "badgesColorSet":["#f51307","#0cc902","#ffff00","#03fcf8","#03fcb1"],
```